# Онлайн радио формат OGG

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли воспроизводить радио, формата OGG в приложении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Можно](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).